# Manipulating .xls columns and rows with Open Refine

Tags: geocoding, xls, google-geocoder, openrefine

I need to manipulate a data set such that it can be mapped with Google Fusion Tables. Current xls data is formatted as follows:

[Image of xls file with personal data anonymized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHU7Y.jpg)

Note that a blank row indicates a new entry. I need the information in the column to be sorted into a rows under the appropriate heading, specifically the address for geocoding. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, do some clean up to merge your second and third column into a single one and then use the feature `Columnize by key/value column` to transpose data in the third and fourth columns into separate fields.

Once this done, Fusion table should be able to geocode the dataset based on the address. If it is not the case, there is plenty of tutorials to geocode a dataset with OpenRefine. See:

- [OpenRefine wiki](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Geocoding),
- [Google Maps](https://blog.ouseful.info/2013/02/20/geocoding-using-the-google-maps-geocoder-via-openrefine/),
- [OpenStreet Map](https://opensas.wordpress.com/2013/06/30/using-openrefine-to-geocode-your-data-using-google-and-openstreetmap-api/),
- [Yahoo Maps](http://kb.refinepro.com/2011/10/fetch-city-and-province-state-based-on.html).